# How to select from multi tables (many to many)?

Tags: java, hibernate

Database: [image]

I want to get a list User, who have the same Monhoc (it has maMH= MH1).
My code :

```
 private final SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Public List<User> listUserMonHoc() {
    try {
        sf.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        Query query = sf.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select a.username, a.name from Monhoc b join b.User a where b.mamh = :id");
        query.setString("id", "MH1");
        List<User> list = query.list();
        sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();

        return list;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("sai");
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        //return null;
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

ERROR message: ERROR: Table 'b.user' doesn't exist.
Thank you!

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: Exception message: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: Please add the relevant stack trace to your question.

Comment: It appears that you are using what Hibernate calls a `scalar` query and what you appear to need is a `entity` query. [This information at jboss](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#d0e13646) will help you understand the difference between scale and entity queries, and help you modify your query so you get back data from Hibernate in the form that you require.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what you mean.
ERROR message: ERROR: Table 'b.user' doesn't exist

Comment: I would use a HQL query. You are trying to access the entity named User which sql query dowesnt understand

Comment: Oh no. When i  replace b.User to User. Error message don't appear but it get ALL user in User table . :(

Comment: Join on `user_monhoc` instead of `monhoc` and add `user_id` from both tables to the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you have problems with your query. First you must join your third table and then search by id from the monhoc table. 
Second there is a problem here

```
Query query = sf.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select a.username, a.name from Monhoc b join b.User a where b.mamh = :id");
```

you must change b.User to User, cause b is allias of your Monhoc table.
So as a native query in MySql will look something like this :

```
SELECT u.username, u.name 
FROM user AS u
INNER JOIN user_monhoc AS um
ON u.username = um.user_id
INNER JOIN monhoc AS m
ON um.mh_id = m.mamh
WHERE ....
```

I am using inner join (it can be different depents on your needs).